# Add html inside embedded ruby pe field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't figure out the syntax to embed html inside my erb pe field.
This is what I'm trying to do ( and it works when I write it this way.

```
<% if weekday == "Monday" %>
  <b> <%= 'Mondays' %> </b>
<% else %>
  <%= 'Mondays' %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm trying to get this to work but can't figure out the syntax. I'm getting a syntax error due to the html

```
<%= weekday == "Monday"? <b>'Mondays'</b> : 'Mondays' %>
```

Any idea? THank you

Comment: I'm afraid it does not do the trick. It displays '<b>Mondays</b>'.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

Comment: Steve and Jake got me the answer

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use [`content_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag); that would be explicit about the mixing of code and content, and leverages a Rails convention.

```
<% weekday = 'Monday' %>
<%= weekday == 'Monday' ? content_tag(:b, 'Mondays') : 'Mondays' %>
```

Result: **Mondays**

FWIW, I think your first code sample is the way to go. [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21029987/2112512) to a similar question makes this point well.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah it became quickly apparent as I started adding code into my if else statement. Nonetheless, I'm happy to know how I would do that if I were to want to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that the string is HTML safe...

```
<%= weekday == "Monday" ? "<b>'Mondays'</b>".html_safe : "'Mondays'" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [`tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag) helper:

```
<%= weekday == 'Monday' ? tag.b('Mondays') : 'Mondays' %>
```

Btw I do not know where the `weekday` variable is coming from and how you initialized it. But if you created it from an instance of `Date` or `Time` then you might be interested in the [`monday?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Time.html#method-i-monday-3F) method too.